# Keeping a variable and string together in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Hey i want to store a piece of text plus a variable in localstorage.
This may seem a bit vague so here is what i mean with this:

```
var something = "text";
localStorage.setItem("localstorage", '"sometext"+something');

function functionz() 
{
var displayed = localStorage.localstorage;
alert(displayed);
}
```

I want to make sure that displayed will display this text: sometexttext
I had it already working by storing "sometext"+something in a variable like this:

```
var something = "text";
localStorage.setItem("localstorage", '"sometext"+something');    

function functionb()
{
var thetext = "sometext"+something;
alert(thetext);
}
```

The second version will give you: (sometexttext), and the first one will give you ("sometext"+something) as raw text. This is ofcourse not what i want and i wonder how i can make it so that it can be stored in localstorage and still display the second result.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `"sometext"+something`.

Comment: That is already what i am using, i think you mean using that instead of having the ' on both sides but if i don't use the ' on both sides, it won't count it as something to be stored, since anything stored in localstorage needs either these " or these ' to be recognized.

Comment: Why would you want to store a *variable name* in the localstorage? Please tell us about your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Well this is a part of my plugin, i want to have a standard URL, then have a variable that is what the user types, this will then be pasted behind the URL and lead you to a certain site depending on what you typed i.e. (someurl.com/location). The url is also different depending on which button you type, but the variable will not change. i.e. (otherurl.com/location). That is the exact problem